# ODBC error connect to SQL Server (ConnectionOpen and Specified SQL server not found)

Tags: sql-server, odbc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfSLC.png)

Hello guy, I'm try to connect to SQL server 2005 by using ODBC Data Source Administrator. But I'm get a error like this image.
I was try:

- TCP/IP enable in Server Config Manager.
- Enable Remote Connection in Surface Area Configuration
- I can telnet [MyIPaddress] 1433

But it's not working. I'm using windows server 2003. I need some help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable TCP connectivity.

By default TCP connectivity is disabled. 
Open SQL Server  Configuration Manager
Navigate to SQL Serrver Network Configuration
Open the "Protocols for "
In the right hand window, right click on TCP and click ENABLE.

you SHOULD now be able to connect to the SQL server.

Comment: Does your computer have a firewall that is actively blocking port 1433?

Comment: i already create exception for port 1433. And i was telnet 1433 successful.

Comment: I'm sorry, you DID say that you could telnet to port 1433 already in your original question and I misread it as CAN'T instead of CAN.